# Removing line separation of widgets on Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have this code but there are lines separating the text widget to the root. How would I remove those lines so it is seamless?

```
import Tkinter, tkFont

root=Tkinter.Tk()
root.geometry('+%d+%d' % (0,0)) #controls where the window is
root.geometry('%dx%d' % (400,400)) #controls window size
background_color = "#fff"

root.config(background=background_color)
customFont = tkFont.Font(family="Agency FB", size=200)

text = Tkinter.Text(root, font=customFont, background=background_color)
text.insert("end","42")
text.config(state='disabled')
text.pack()
text.place(x=10,y=10)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: If you call `text.place()` (which I don't recommend), there is no point in calling `text.pack()`. Use one or the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `borderwidth` with `highlightthickness` or `relief` options. Either one should work.

```
text = Tkinter.Text(root, ... , relief="flat")

text = Tkinter.Text(root, ... , borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0) #thanks to Bryan Oakley
```

If you want to check out other options of widgets, you should take a look at [effbot](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm)

Comment: `highlightthickness` is another option to consider.

Comment: @BryanOakley I tried to use it but couldn't make it work. After adding `highlightthickness=0` there still is a border.

Comment: You need to set both `borderwidth` and `highlightthickness` to zero if you want absolutely no border.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and link to that site! :)