# Removing empty border from Text widget for Tkinter for Python

Tags: python, tkinter

I have two Text widgets being placed in a tkinter window. My problem is that the empty border of the second line is hiding part of the first line.

[image]

I looked at `http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm` but all the default boarder stuff is set to 0.

Here is my code, thank you!

```
import Tkinter, tkFont, random    

root=Tkinter.Tk()
root.geometry('+%d+%d' % (0,0)) #controls where the window is
root.geometry('%dx%d' % (600,350)) #controls window size
root.config(background="#fff")

firstLine = "First Line"
secondLine = "Second Line" 

customFont = tkFont.Font(family="Agency FB",
                         size=100,
                         weight="bold")


text1 = Tkinter.Text(root,
                    font=customFont,
                    background="#fff",
                    fg="#000",
                    relief="flat")

text1.insert("end",firstLine)

text1.config(state='disabled')
text1.place(x=10,y=10) #controls where the text is placed

text2 = Tkinter.Text(root,
                    font=customFont,
                    background="#fff",
                    fg="#000",
                    relief="flat")

text2.insert("end",secondLine)

text2.config(state='disabled')
text2.place(x=10,y=125) #controls where the number is placed

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Isn't this just a duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23693586/removing-line-seperation-of-widgets-on-tkinter ? Did you try the advice given in answers to that other question?

Comment: I changed it to the "borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0 option" and it didn't fix it. Maybe it wasn't clear enough. I am bad with words so here is a picture: http://oi62.tinypic.com/34658nn.jpg

Comment: Thank you Kevin. I should have known to do that...

Comment: I think what you are calling a border isn't a border at all. It's the just natural amount of whitespace that Tkinter places around text to make it legible. In other words, it's not part of the widget per se, it's part of the font.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things that I think are going wrong.

First, you claim that the border of the second is over the first, but that's not technically accurate. What you are seeing isn't a border, it's the spacing that surrounds a font. Setting the border or highlightthickness attributes to zero won't solve this problem because it is space internal to the text widget.

Second, it seems like you might be making an assumption that a font of size `100` is going to be 100 pixels tall. That is not the case -- the `100` means it is 100 *points* tall, not 100 *pixels* tall. You can specify a size of `-100` to mean 100 pixels tall.

Third, you are using `place`, which means you are explicitly placing the second widget on top of the first. Again, my guess is that you're placing it at a y coordinate of 125 because you think the other one is 100 widgets tall, which is simply not the case.

If you're trying to precisely place text, you should probably be using the canvas with some text items. Widgets aren't the best tool for this particular job.